# Unable to get .htaccess working

Tags: apache, .htaccess

As an experienced web developer, I feel like an idiot posting this.  Somehow I tend to have issues with `.htaccess`.  I'm trying to route all requests within `/wiki` to my index.php with the following...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ./ /index.php [L]
```

Virutal host:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.local
        DocumentRoot "/var/www/mysite/public_html"
        <Directory "/var/www/mysite/public_html">
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I'm trying to access `http://mysite.local/wiki/asdf` and getting a 404 error.

Apache's error log shows nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing what the Yii Framework uses...

```
RewriteEngine On

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

Answer (score 0):

If `/wiki` is an existing folder in your `public_html` root folder, and your `index.php` file is in the `wiki` folder, then you can give the following a try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wiki
RewriteRule index\.php - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
```

If the `wiki` folder does not exist, and you're doing all the work at the root:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule index\.php - [F,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteRule wiki/(.*) index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Now give this a try! To rewrite non-existence `/wiki` and `/wiki/` and `/wiki/$var` into `/index.php`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/wiki/?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php
```

Comment: I'm trying to only rewrite directories/paths that don't exist, which is why I thought using Wordpress' .htaccess would do it.

Comment: Which non-existence, directories or files?